# Spatially merging two netCDF raster layers into one layer while using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, merge, netcdf

I tried to merge two .nc-files into one within ArcMap. There is one file containing the specific values for North America and one containing the values for South America (see the image below).

[image]

My procedure was as follows: I added the two .nc-files to ArcMap via:

-> Make NetCDF Raster Layer

Onwards I tried to merge them via

-> Merge (Data management)

However, I cannot drag and drop the two nc layers into the Merge-tool as it says the dropped items are invalid. I did also not find another tool which joins those two netCDF raster layers.

I need the two layers in one as I like to perform a subsequent and consistent aggregation of the values for whole America to a coarser resolution via the tool

-> "Aggregate (Spatial Analyist)"

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [usage section](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm#ESRI_USAGES_E8201E34BDEA4B4BB2E2F55310952EA8) of the help file on the Merge tool it clearly states for the inputs parameter "....datasets can be point, line, or polygon feature classes or tables".  Merge works on VECTOR data not RASTER.

You need to convert your netCDF into raster layers and then use the mosaic to new raster tool to combine them into a single raster. Read the help file and explore the [Multidimension toolbox](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/multidimension-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-multidimension-toolbox.htm).